# How can I handle refs for Pressable in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am working on a project using React Native with Typescript. I am trying to forwardRef to my Pressable component but I keep getting an error that states:

> Blockquote
> 'Pressable' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Pressable'?

I also decided to use the "typeof Pressable" and the error was gone but the ref passed to the rendered Pressable component throw a new error below:

> Blockquote
> Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
> Type 'View | null' is not assignable to type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<PressableProps & RefAttributes> | null'.

I have reproduced the code below:

```
const Item = React.forwardRef<Pressable, ItemProps>((props, ref) => {
    return (
      <Pressable ref={ref}>
        <Text>Item 1</Text>
      </Pressable>
    )
})
```

How can I get rid of this error and have the ref type properly mapped to the Pressable component?

Comment: `Pressable` itself forwards the ref to `View`, so maybe try `React.forwardRef<View, ItemProps>`? https://tsplay.dev/WJ17Vm

Comment: That works. Thank you. Could you provide the answer here so I can mark it as the right answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `Pressable` itself also forwards its ref (to `View`). This can be seen from its type: `React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<PressableProps & React.RefAttributes<View>>`. A simple way to see what's going on is to pass a dummy `{} as any` ref to `Pressable` and hover over `ref`:

```
const test = <Pressable ref={{} as any}/>
// (property) RefAttributes<View>.ref?: React.Ref<View> | undefined
```

This shows that `Pressable` expects `ref` to have type `Ref<View>` instead of a `Ref<Pressable>`, which can be achieved by passing `View` as the first type parameter to `forwardRef`:

```
type ItemProps = {label: string}

const Item = React.forwardRef<View, ItemProps>(
  (props, ref) =>
    <Pressable ref={ref}>
      <div>Item 1: {props.label}</div>
    </Pressable>
)

const Test = () => {
  const ref = React.createRef<View>();
  return <Item label='Test' ref={ref}/>
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/mxya1W)